# Directive/Factory Not Working in Production

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flash, heroku

I have a directive that prints out flash messages for users. Everything works fine on my localhost but as soon as I test it out on Heroku, the flash message does not appear. Here is the controller.

```
angular.module("alerts")

.controller("AlertsController", alertController)

alertController.$inject = ['Flash']

function alertController(Flash) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.flash = Flash;
}
```

The directive...

```
angular.module("alerts")

.directive('flash', flash);

flash.$inject = ['$timeout'];

function flash ($timeout){
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     replace: true,
     scope: {
         text: '=',
         type: '='
     },
     template: '<div id="flash_message" class="notification" ng-class="type"> {{text}} hello </div>',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
         $timeout(function(){
             element.remove();
         }, 5000);
     }
  }
}
```

And the factory that handles storing the flash messages.

```
angular.module("alerts")

.factory("Flash", flash)

function flash() {

  var messages = [];

  var results = {
    messages: messages,
    printMessage: printMessage,
    addMessage: addMessage
  }

  return results;

  function printMessage() {
    return results.messages
  }

  function addMessage(message) {
    results.messages.push(message);
  }
}
```

My html code...

```
<div ng-controller="AlertsController as alerts">
  <div ng-repeat="message in alerts.flash.messages">
    <flash type="message.type" text="message.text"></flash>
  </div>
</div>
```

No error appears on the console. The funny thing is the flash message is presented in the html doesn't load.

This is what is shown in localhost.

```
<div ng-repeat="message in alerts.flash.messages" class="ng-scope">
  <div id="flash_message" class="notification ng-binding ng-isolate-scope success" ng-class="type" type="message.type" text="message.text"> Your link has been copied! hello </div>
</div>
```

But on heroku production

```
<div ng-repeat="message in alerts.flash.messages" class="ng-scope"></div>
```

I'm creating the flash in my code via..

```
Flash.addMessage({type: "success", text: "Your link has been copied!"});
```

My question is, why does this not appear on my production code but it appears on my localhost and how do I fix it?

Comment: are you minifying your javascript?

Comment: What browser are you checking the console for errors? Some browsers display some errors, while others just warnings or none. Try Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera. Besides, do you know if your server is caching the output? Since these are static files, caching is very likelly to happen. Make sure the one you are downloading is the latest one or a cached file.

Comment: I'm using `ngannotate-rails` to help me minify. As for the browser, I'm checking all browsers.

Comment: Looks like a problem farther up the chain to me. `Flash.addMessage` isn't happening, or what it does isn't adding to `alerts.flash.messages`. **More debugging is needed.**

Comment: @KevinB The flash message is added as soon as the code is called. It looks like this. `<div ng-repeat="message in alerts.flash.messages" class="ng-scope"></div>` Every time I run the code another one of those divs load into the appropriate HTML location. This event occurs across the board on all pages.

Comment: Can someone please explain why they downvoted? I feel like this is a valid question with enough appropriate info.

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question itself for it to be answered, more research (debugging) needs to occur before this can be a useful question. You said it yourself, your code works. the problem must be environmental.

Comment: I have no idea how to further clarify the question. It works on the localhost but on heroku no flash message appears. I've documented the html code that appears between both local and production. What other debugging do I need to show? The console isn't telling me anything besides the fact the code was executed.

Comment: Did you open your network tab to ensure all of the files are loading properly?

Comment: Yes, every file is loaded properly.

Comment: Open your debugger, put a break point on the add messages function, and try again. Does the breakpoint get hit? does the function properly update the array? (assuming your using non-minified code on the production server for debugging, or at least a source map)

Comment: Yes it does update the array correctly.

Comment: try: link: function(scope, element, attrs){console.log("I should work");} as a link function in your 'flash' directive, to check if the directive is properly loaded on Heroku

Comment: @manube Nothing shows up on my console when the flash is added in.

Comment: if you set your flash directive link function like so: link: function(scope, element, attrs){console.log("see if it works");} and nothing shows in your console, then the flash directive is not loaded by angularjs. Because it should log to the console at load time, even before you flash a message. Which would mean the task runner you are using for building your app is not well configured

Comment: From my other testing every other angular feature works which makes me think that all files ARE loaded. I'm not really sure how to fix this considering I'm using heroku and heroku bundles the assets together in a Rails app.

Comment: It could be a CORS problem on loading flash messages. Try to look this article: http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/

Comment: I guess it can be the problem in names of directive function and service. They have the same names: flash. Try to rename one of it.

Comment: Is each piece of code above wrapped in a separate IIFE?  If not, you have two `function flash()` objects, one for the directive and one for the factory.  If they're just in separate files but not wrapped `(function() { [...] })()`, they will both be on the global scope and could be causing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming my file name and the internal function inside my directive solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, renaming the file name must have solved your problem. But the question is, why was it working earlier on localhost? I think on localhost all your javascript files loaded instantly and the function 'flash' of respective factory and directive got registered correctly.

But running on heroku or any other remote server, you will encounter problem as the controller or directive may register different 'flash' function than what they must register.

A plausible reason could be that angularjs's library file (from your server or cdn) was loaded into DOM a bit later than your files like controller.js, service.js or directive.js. Thats why the DOM didn't recognised the angular syntax of .controller() or .service(), etc at start. And consequently one of your global 'flash' function(of directive or factory) was overridden.

First of all I would suggest you to rename, which you have already done, and secondly, do not use global functions inside directive or factory.

I hope this explains.